# When using inner properties it show the error message in design view

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I'm doing expose the ClientSideEvent and I using [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)].

Aspx code:

```
<uc1:WebUserControl2 ID="WebUserControl21" runat="server" >
    <TestProperty></TestProperty>
</uc1:WebUserControl2>
```

When I type the < TestProperty>< /TestProperty> , it will show the 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not have a public property named 'TestProperty' in design view. What is the problem and how to solve it?

Behind code:

```
[ParseChildren(true)]
public partial class WebUserControl2 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public String TestProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewState["TestProperty"] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["TestProperty"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old issue pls refer to link. [ASP.NET Custom/User Control With Children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044938/asp-net-custom-user-control-with-children) and
 [How can I include additional markup within a 'Content' inner property of an ASP.Net WebControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745886/how-can-i-include-additional-markup-within-a-content-inner-property-of-an-asp) and this http://pastebin.com/hLq4bsC5

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6(v=vs.85).aspx Please scroll down until the end of the page.